# Unrecognized configuration section system.ftpServer for azure

Tags: azure, iis, cloud

I'm trying to configure web.config for my Azure web app service. I want to restrict the ftp access to only specific URLs. But when i am adding the  tag, it is giving me the error -

```
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.ftpServer.
```

Can you please guide me where i am doing the mistake.
Thanks in advance

My Web.config file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>

  <location path="<<FTP hostname>>">

    <system.ftpServer>
     <security>
      <authorization>
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="administrators" permissions="Read, Write" />
      </authorization>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <add fileExtension=".exe" allowed="false" />
          <add fileExtension=".bat" allowed="false" />
          <add fileExtension=".cmd" allowed="false" />
        </fileExtensions>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000" maxUrl="1024" />
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="_vti_bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
      <ipSecurity enableReverseDns="false" allowUnlisted="true">
        <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />
        <add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="false" />
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.ftpServer>

  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some verisons of IIS donot support 'system.ftpServer' configuration or you need to download ftp module manually. You can reference the artice https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.ftpserver and check your IIS version.